# Lagrange interpolation in 3D space

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, 3d, interpolation

Has anyone ever implemented a working algorithm for the Lagrange interpolation, working in three dimensional space, going through three or more points, which can somehow get plotted with Visual Studio?

Comment: So, what have you tried? Do you actually understand theoretically how the interpolation functions?

Comment: well, i have  a lot of difficulties to understand the lagrange interpolation or better how to implement mathamatic formulas in c++. a few minutes from now i got the feetback that a plotted line through four points would work just fine for the task

Answer (score 1):

the theory:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_973360&src_vid=_zK_KhHW6og&v=anbLwKsESew

a linear interpolation example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_973360&src_vid=_zK_KhHW6og&v=anbLwKsESew

a quadratic interpolation example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?src_vid=anbLwKsESew&annotation_id=annotation_118813&v=QWvgMUZ5rqs&feature=iv